# Resetting a div's content?

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a way to reset a divs content.

I have a div(container) and div(card) that hold images from an API. How could I reset the divs content that is already populated?

````
    //Here is how I am populating the card div
    const card = document.createElement('div');
    card.setAttribute('class', 'card');

    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = photo["urls"].regular;

    container.appendChild(card);
    card.appendChild(img);```
````

How could I refresh the div alone to achieve a 'refresh' to load the new content?

Comment: Well that kinda depends on what you're "refreshing" the div back to. If you want them to be empty that's easy, you should just be able to use `card.innerHTML = ""`

Comment: Clarification on what you mean by "reset" would be helpful. Do you intend to empty the element of all contents, remove the element, refresh it wish another set of data, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

```
container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
```

This will remove the image and the last card added. Then you can just call the same code to add the new card.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '';`

Example in JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/gbvqf8ru/8/

Comment: If you do this, you'll need to re-add the card div.